# ApexCharts: Can I have the y-axis the middle of the chart, instead of left or right?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, apexcharts

I understand that I can have the y-axis on the left or right (opposite:true), but I am making a comparison chart (using positive and negative values for the two items being compared).
I think it would make more sense for the chart to have the axis in the center instead of at one end. How can I achieve that, or is that not possible?

Current behavior:
[Current Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxVGQ.png)

Desired behavior:
[Desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL0Qs.png)

I have tried making the y axis floating, but that just moves the axis out of the chart frame, I guess. And I have tried adding an offset to the axis. Adding the offset moves the labels, but the axis line on the left is still visible. Plus, since there is no space between the two items (red and blue), the labels just overlaps on top of it. So I don't think that is the way to go here.

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for, but have you considered just splitting it up into 2 separate charts and hide the axis for the left one?

Comment: May create more nuisance, isn't it? On different screens, I will need to make sure that elements from two different charts are aligning properly. Also, I would need to create a completely custom functionality to enable downloading the chart.